# How to apply MeanIoU to multioutput model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a model based on MobileNet v2 with 2 outputs: class (cat/dog) and face coordinates. So "class" output has BinaryCrossentropy loss and "bbox" output has YOLO los (in code).
The problem is, when I try to apply metrics (accuracy for class and MeanIOU to bbox):

- On random dataset: they show strange results (accuracy == 0, miou == 1 all the time).
- On real dataset (images and labels): fit() throws error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I suspect that I messed up outputs and metrics somehow, it would be nice if someone with more experience in tensorflow would take a look at it.

There is the code (with random dataset to reproduce):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# generate fake dataset
IMG_SIZE = 200
num_of_samples = 2000
images = tf.random.uniform((num_of_samples, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3), minval=0, maxval=1)
images = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(images)
label_classes = tf.random.uniform((num_of_samples, 1), minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)
label_classes = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(label_classes)
label_coords = tf.random.uniform((num_of_samples, 4), minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float16)
label_coords = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(label_coords)
labels = tf.data.Dataset.zip((label_classes, label_coords))
train = tf.data.Dataset.zip((images, labels))
train = train.shuffle(num_of_samples)
train = train.batch(8)
train = train.prefetch(4)

num_of_samples = 500
images = tf.random.uniform((num_of_samples, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3), minval=0, maxval=1)
images = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(images)
label_classes = tf.random.uniform((num_of_samples, 1), minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)
label_classes = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(label_classes)
label_coords = tf.random.uniform((num_of_samples, 4), minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float16)
label_coords = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(label_coords)
labels = tf.data.Dataset.zip((label_classes, label_coords))
valid = tf.data.Dataset.zip((images, labels))
valid = valid.shuffle(num_of_samples)
valid = valid.batch(8)
valid = valid.prefetch(4)

# Model with two outputs
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, GlobalMaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2

def cnn_from_transfer():
    IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
    input_layer = Input(shape=IMG_SHAPE)
    base_net = MobileNetV2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')(input_layer)
    # Classification
    h1 = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(base_net)
    class1 = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(h1)
    class2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(class1)
    # Bounding box
    h2 = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(base_net)
    regress1 = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(h2)
    regress2 = Dense(4, activation='sigmoid')(regress1)

    return Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[class2, regress2])

model = cnn_from_transfer()

# Losses
def localization_loss(y_true, yhat):            
    delta_coord = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_true[:,:2] - yhat[:,:2]))
    h_true = y_true[:,3] - y_true[:,1] 
    w_true = y_true[:,2] - y_true[:,0] 
    h_pred = yhat[:,3] - yhat[:,1] 
    w_pred = yhat[:,2] - yhat[:,0] 
    delta_size = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(w_true - w_pred) + tf.square(h_true-h_pred))
    return delta_coord + delta_size
classloss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
regressloss = localization_loss

# Train
model.compile(
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, decay=0.00001),
    loss=[classloss, regressloss],
    metrics=[[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()], [tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes=2)]],
)

history = model.fit(train, epochs=5, validation_data=valid)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: here the mea_iou is for semantic segmentaiton model.

Comment: What should I use then? Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: Your modeling is more like object detection (class and bbox) but that mean_iou is written for semantic segmentaiton model. I think you need iou for object detection, (i.e. https://github.com/Balupurohit23/IOU-for-bounding-box-regression-in-Keras).

Answer (score 0):

As M.Innat said in comments, tf MeanIoU is not applicable to my case (bboxes), so I need to make my own custom metric (`iou_metric` function below). Moreover I found out that `BinaryAccuracy` should be used instead of regular `Accuracy`. The rest is fine.

Here is correct code:

```py
def iou_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    aog = tf.abs(tf.transpose(y_true)[2] - tf.transpose(y_true)[0] + 1) * tf.abs(tf.transpose(y_true)[3] - tf.transpose(y_true)[1] + 1)
    aop = tf.abs(tf.transpose(y_pred)[2] - tf.transpose(y_pred)[0] + 1) * tf.abs(tf.transpose(y_pred)[3] - tf.transpose(y_pred)[1] + 1)
    overlap_0 = tf.maximum(tf.transpose(y_true)[0], tf.transpose(y_pred)[0])
    overlap_1 = tf.maximum(tf.transpose(y_true)[1], tf.transpose(y_pred)[1])
    overlap_2 = tf.minimum(tf.transpose(y_true)[2], tf.transpose(y_pred)[2])
    overlap_3 = tf.minimum(tf.transpose(y_true)[3], tf.transpose(y_pred)[3])
    intersection = (overlap_2 - overlap_0 + 1) * (overlap_3 - overlap_1 + 1)
    union = aog + aop - intersection
    iou = intersection / union
    iou = tf.keras.backend.clip(iou, 0.0 + tf.keras.backend.epsilon(), 1.0 - tf.keras.backend.epsilon())
    return iou    

model.compile(
    optimizer = opt,
    loss=[classloss, regressloss],
    metrics=[[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()], [iou_metric]],
)
```